# Tile based game engine for WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I showed my friend a demo of what I was doing with the farseer physics engine on the windows phone and he wanted to know if farseer would be good for a game he wants to develop. It's a tile based game so I said I don't think farseer would be the best choice (correct me if i'm wrong).

Are there any tile game engines for windows phone? Think tile based like the original Zelda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Farseer is a physics engine, **not** a game engine. Which one is he looking for?

If he is looking for a game engine check out [FlatRedBall](http://flatredball.com). Alliteratively, if he is looking for something help create the maps, check out [tIDE](https://colinvella.github.io/tIDE/). It has a UI for laying down tiles, and a "engine" component to draw them in your game.

If he wanted, he could even mix the two. Use FRB for the screen management, GUI, etc... and use tIDE to help draw the maps. There is really no reason why that can't be done.